# jQuery on click function is not working multiple time by a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some element where there is label which are given same class name. So when the label will be clicked the function should run. But it is only running 2 times and then not fire. I am disabling all the field in the parent div by clicking the label. I need it whenever it will be clicked.

Here are my attempts below.

My view:

```
    <div class="physicalExamTable">
    <div class="col-md-12 noLeftPadding noRightPadding">
        <div class="col-md-6 noLeftPadding">
            <div class="form-inline topPaddingSmall">
                <label class="testLabel btnColorInactive">CBC:</label>
                %{--<a class="btn testLabel btnColorInactive">CBC:</a>--}%
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="labCbcTbl" name="CBC:" activeStatus="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>WBC</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><g:textField name="wbc" class="form-control"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="physicalExamTable">
    <div class="col-md-12 noLeftPadding noRightPadding">
        <div class="col-md-6 noLeftPadding">
            <div class="form-inline topPaddingSmall">
                <label class="btnColorInactive testLabel">Chemistry Panel:</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="labChemistryTbl1" name="Chemistry Panel 1:">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Na</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><g:textField name="na" class="form-control"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('#physicalExamDiv').on('click', 'label.testLabel', function() {
        var parentDiv = $(this).closest('.physicalExamTable');
        var currentLabel = $(this);
        if (currentLabel.hasClass("btnColorInactive")) {
            parentDiv.find("*").prop('disabled', false);
            currentLabel.removeClass("btnColorInactive").addClass("btnColorActive");
            parentDiv.find("table").attr("activeStatus", "1");
        } else {
            parentDiv.find("*").prop('disabled', true);
            currentLabel.removeClass("btnColorActive").addClass("btnColorInactive");
            parentDiv.find("table").attr("activeStatus", "0");
        }
    });
```

It is enabling the field one time, disabling the field one time. But after that is not firing.

Comment: where is element with `id physicalExamDiv`

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle.net or plunker for it ?

Comment: Where *exactly* are you calling `$('#physicalExamDiv').on('click', ...` from?  This would occur if you add this event handler multiple times.  Add a `console.log("click")` just inside the handler (before var parentDiv) and see how often if actually fires.

Comment: @guradio `id physicalExamDiv` holds all the div with the class `physicalExamTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working for the third time as you are disabling the link:

```
parentDiv.find("*").prop('disabled', true);
```

**Note**: this is browser dependent.

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/zgmbqv11/

```
<label>click</label>
$("label").click(function() { 
    alert("ok");
    $("label").prop("disabled", true)
})
```

The fiddle in IE11 gives one alert, in chrome it continues to work.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Since i misunderstood the question, I've rewritten the answer.

This is because your'e using the `.prop` function to set the disabled property to true or false. You should remove the attribute by using `.removeAttr('disabled')`.

```
$("#physicalExamDiv").on("click", "label.testLabel", function() {
    var parentDiv = $(this).closest('.physicalExamTable');
    var currentLabel = $(this);

    if (currentLabel.hasClass("btnColorInactive")) {
        parentDiv.find("*").removeAttr("disabled");
        currentLabel.removeClass("btnColorInactive").addClass("btnColorActive");
        parentDiv.find("table").attr("activeStatus", "1");
    } else {
        parentDiv.find("*").attr("disabled", true);
        currentLabel.removeClass("btnColorActive").addClass("btnColorInactive");
        parentDiv.find("table").attr("activeStatus", "0");
    }
});
```

Comment: If the event listener was not working at all, then it would not, as **per the question** "*enable the field one time, disable the field one time. But after that not fire.*"

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m I've rewritten the answer.

Answer (score 0):

freedomn-m's idea works for me. I added this line `parentDiv.find("label").prop('disabled', false)` as follows:

```
$('#physicalExamDiv').on('click', 'label.testLabel', function() {
        var parentDiv = $(this).closest('.physicalExamTable');
        var currentLabel = $(this);
        if (currentLabel.hasClass("btnColorInactive")) {
            parentDiv.find("*").prop('disabled', false);
            currentLabel.removeClass("btnColorInactive").addClass("btnColorActive");
            parentDiv.find("table").attr("activeStatus", "1");
        } else {
            parentDiv.find("*").prop('disabled', true);
            currentLabel.removeClass("btnColorActive").addClass("btnColorInactive");
            parentDiv.find("table").attr("activeStatus", "0");
        }
        parentDiv.find("label").prop('disabled', false);
    });
```

Comment: You could also: `parentDiv.find("*").not("label").prop('disabled', true);`